# Using bugzilla webservices in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, bugzilla, xmlrpcclient

I want to use the bugzilla webservice APIs in PHP. The issue seems to be the XML-RPC client. I have gone through similar questions, but dont want to install the whole Zend framework only for the client. Is there a way to separate out the Zend XML-RPC client or can you suggest some other client that you have used?

I am trying with the IXR_Library client but having issues there. Can post the code if anyone is interested in that. Let me know if you want any more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, you need only `Zend\XmlRpc` folder and `Zend\Exception.php` from Zend package for this. There are no other dependencies.

Comment: actually not. i tried taking it out and it depends on the Http/Client.php as well.

Comment: So, copy them too. What is the problem with it?

Comment: the problem is that i end up copying the whole Zend/* folder meeting one after other dependencies. This seems bulky and unnecessary to me to get only the client functionality.

Comment: Nice suggestion this one. I tried it but it doesnt seem to be supporting cookies which seem to be required for bugzilla functioning. I got it working using Zend APIs though, but the size of the Zend folder is 30 MB :)... Still looking for alternatives.

Comment: cleaned up the zend folder and got it working with around 630KB of dependencies. I can live with that for now and since it was what the answer suggested, accepting it as the right one.